Why are there some redundant typedef declarations in the libstdc++ source code?
I am reading the source code of std::pair implemented by GCC. And I got confused by the redundant typedef as below. I know I must miss something, but just a few functions use first_type and second_type, like the move assignment operator. Why doesn't it just use _T1 and _T2? Thank you.
template<typename _T1, typename _T2>
struct pair
: public __pair_base<_T1, _T2>
{
    typedef _T1 first_type;    ///< The type of the `first` member
    typedef _T2 second_type;   ///< The type of the `second` member

    _T1 first;                 ///< The first member
    _T2 second;                ///< The second member

    /// Move assignment operator
    constexpr pair&
    operator=(pair&& __p)
    noexcept(_S_nothrow_assignable<_T1, _T2>())
    requires (_S_assignable<_T1, _T2>())
    {
        first = std::forward<first_type>(__p.first);
        second = std::forward<second_type>(__p.second);
        return *this;
    }
};



It's probably specified that std::pair need to have those type-aliases in the scope of the class. It does simplify things when you use templates or auto type deduction, and do not know the actual types used when creating the pair.

@Eason additional information goes to the question, not in comments.

Its specified here: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/pairs.pair

@πάνταῥεῖ I attached the link. Thank you.

@Someprogrammerdude I can see this point, but why does it use the alias in the move assignment operator?

It's not redundant. There is no way to access _T1 and _T2 from outside of the class, and it's required by standard. You will find this pattern very often when class wants to expose template type back to its user.

Regarding the use of both the template types and the type-aliases in the move-assignment operator, I don't think there's a specific reason. Perhaps different people worked on the code, one used the template types, one used the type aliases?

@Yksisarvinen I think it's pretty persuasive. Would you like to give an example? Thank you.
